# Executing task npm run test in Visual Code Studio stopped working

Tags: openlayers, json, node-js

I was working normaly in Visual Code Studio and everything was ok, then stopped uploading my changes from js in localhost server page.With npm start and build:server is running and built.
But npm run test :

```
olproject@1.0.0 test C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OLproject
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

"Error: no test specified"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! olproject@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the olproject@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-08T09_20_03_724Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: npm run test <


> olproject@1.0.0 test C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OLproject
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

"Error: no test specified"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! olproject@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the olproject@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-08T09_24_30_953Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

and json:

```
{
  "name": "olproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel -p 1995 index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^6.2.1",
    "ol-layerswitcher": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  }
}
```

A complete log of this run:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~pretest: olproject@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: olproject@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OLproject\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: CWD: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OLproject
10 silly lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1' ]
11 silly lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle olproject@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: olproject@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid olproject@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OLproject
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error olproject@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the olproject@1.0.0 test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried with changing VCS version to the previouse one,but its still the same.
I tried with npm cache clear solution too, because of npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE.
Followed by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

The package.json contanins

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel -p 1995 index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
```

So if you run a `test`, it displays the said message and return with error code 1, which is what you are seeing.

You can skip running the test, remove it, or remove the `&& exit 1` which is what stops the execution flow.

Comment: I did ti and got  "Error: no test specified" when Executing task: npm run test...and when npm run start: Server running at http://localhost:60916 - configured port 1995 could not be used. But when I make changes in js it refresh the page but still dont change anything